# Wordpress menu - icon doesn't show as specified in 'after' of wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

Encountered a menu which needed a fontawesome icon appended. The icon works in `before` but not in `after`:

```
function mobile_menu()
{
    $mobile = array(
        'theme_location' => 'mobile',
        'container'       => false,
        'container_class' => '',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => '',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => false,
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '<span><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'          => 0,
        'walker'          => new CUSTOM_Walker()
    );

    wp_nav_menu($mobile);
}
```

Problem persists with both different and no wrapper elements.
No CSS or JS is used to manipulate the menu.

How do I get the fontawesome icon to work with the `after` class?

Comment: Based on the code you've shown, what you have would work. It will place your HTML markup after the link markup. Is your `Custom_Walker` not outputting the `after` parameter? I would look there first.

Comment: Since it was in your custom walker, I'm voting to close this as a typo issue since it's specific and the original code provide only a hint at what could be the issue (as seen in my previous comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody could have answered this with the above input. In the custom walker I have the following line:

```
$output .= sprintf("\n <li%s>%s<a href='%s' target='%s'>%s</a>\n", $li_class, $before, $item->url, $target, $item->title, $after);
```

The way `sprintf` works this would never append the after pseudo element. I was missing a `%s` right after the closing `a` tag.

This is how it should be:

```
$output .= sprintf("\n <li%s>%s<a href='%s' target='%s'>%s</a>%s\n", $li_class, $before, $item->url, $target, $item->title, $after);
```